# blurry pdf in Preview & Safari on OSX Mojave

Tags: safari, software-update, pdf, preview, mojave

I have just updated from High Sierra to Mojave and discovered that Preview displays PDF files in an extremely blurry way (before the update it was fine). My screen is 27'' Thunderbolt display.

The interesting point is that even after the update Chrome (on the left) displays PDF files in a much better and more readable way compared to Safari (on the right):
[image]

The link used above is https://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.1585.pdf?view=FitH p. 2.
Both browsers were opened side-by-side in a fullscreen mode.

I think that fortunately the update has not affected Chrome (also Acrobat Reader works fine for me). But apparently the update has affected something used in Preview (and other apps, such as Skim), presumably PDFKit as mentioned [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8531638).

On the Internet I have read that this issue might be related to antialiasing, but [none of the recipes solve the issue](https://blog.macsales.com/46527-is-macos-mojave-making-some-fonts-blurry-heres-how-to-fix-it).
Is there any other solution, or shall I hope for a fix in the next update?

**Update.** After updating to Catalina it seems that the situation has improved: [image: Chrome (on the left) compared to Safari (on the right)]
Hopefully in the future versions they are not going to break this again.

Comment: The native PDF engine in Mojave does not use subpixel antialiasing anymore, I think that is the difference between Chrome and Safari. If you zoom in on the pixels using the Digital Color Meter app, you'll see that Safari only uses grayscale antialiasing, which makes the text look less black. I have not found any hidden setting to turn subpixel antialiasing back on for PDFs. I strongly suggest sending some feedback to Apple about this, otherwise it will never get changed: https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html.

Comment: That's a shame the expensive Macbook pro is now useless for research purposes. Apple couldn't care less with this issue. It is time to move to Linux for good.

Comment: @Parham to be fair it seems that in Catalina they have fixed the issue, I have updated my post